# How to get Yahoo Finance Key Statistics such as return on equity

Tags: yahoo-finance

I would like to get key statistics data for a given symbol in Yahoo! Finance.

I found a few ways to get statistics data using Yahoo Finance API. 
For example, to get Apple’s name (n), ask (a), bid (b), market cap(j1), 
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=nabj1
(e.g. http://www.jarloo.com/yahoo_finance/)

But I would like to extract more information such as return on equity and enterprise value. 
How can I do this? 
I cannot even fetch these values from web scraping either.

Answer (score 1):

Key statistics can be accessed by calling the following API-Call:

```
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/AAPL?modules=defaultKeyStatistics
```

This includes enterprise value and book value.
I have not found a way to get return on equity directly from Yahoo Finance but it could be calculated from other values found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47505102/7155708) answer.

Edit:

Return on equity can be found in the financial data:

```
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/AAPL?modules=financialData
```

Comment: try `modules=financialData` and then look for `returnOnEquity`